Dimensionality of the orthogonal projections of linear subspaces
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two linear subspaces of a linear space $C$. Let $A'$ denote the orthogonal projection of $A$ onto $B$, and $B'$ the orthogonal projection of $B$ onto $A$. Is it always true that $dim(A')=dim(B')$?

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.
